# Leaking basement caused by poorly graded sidewalk

Tags: foundation

Along our sidewalk on the side of the house we have a 5ft section of cement that slopes directly to the house. The water pools from the steps back towards the window. About 8 inches to the right of the window is where a leak comes down the interior basement wall. I have tried caulking the crack that was along the foundation and the sidewalk. It may have slowed the leak but there still is water that comes in when it pools up there. This pools up simply because of the grade and not the gutters.

Honestly,  I am fearing a very expensive fix for someone to tear up the sidewalk and lay new cement. Are there any other options that I can try before going that route? If not, any clue how much it would cost to fix something like that in Colorado?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to get the slab mudjacked (its a process where a series of holes are drilled in the slab on the low side, concrete is injected in under the slab and the hydraulic pressure lifts the slab up.  when the concrete sets, the slab is permanently lifted the way you want it to be.  just do a search for mudjacking in your area.